# Load yaml file from a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

Is there anyway to load a `yaml` file which is stored in the ***Amazon S3 bucket***? I tried giving the `url` in the `YAML.load_file()` method but it is not picking up the file. Please give your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your website as string using `open-uri`, then load that string as YAML.

```rb
    require "open-uri"
    
    yaml_content = open("http://www.google.com"){|f| f.read}
    yaml_data = YAML::load(yaml_content)
    yaml_data["content"]
```

Comment: Please explain a bit your answer - please don't post code solely.

Comment: `require ""` is invalid syntax. Edit your answer?